# Can not bind Ctrl-o in Bash inside iTerm2 on macOS Sierra

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm2, macos-sierra

I am not able for the life of me to rebind Ctrl-o on iTerm2/Bash.

Here is my stty -a flags for cchars:

```
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Here is my .inputrc:

```
set bind-tty-special-chars off
Control-o: "> output"
```

Rebind C-u works though, so the inconsistency is driving me crazy. Would appreciate it if someone could explain why to me.

Answer (score 0):

short: the feature applies only to *editing* characters; `discard` is not an editing character.

longer: use the source.  There's a table in `lib/readline/bind.c` which has this entry:

```
  { "bind-tty-special-chars",   &_rl_bind_stty_chars,           0 },
```

which assigns the option name to the address of a variable.  The variable is tested a few places in libreadline, ultimately going to this function:

```
    /* Rebind all of the tty special chars that readline worries about back 
       to self-insert.  Call this before saving the current terminal special 
       chars with save_tty_chars().  This only works on POSIX termios or termio 
       systems. */
    void
    rl_tty_unset_default_bindings (kmap)
         Keymap kmap;
    {
      /* Don't bother before we've saved the tty special chars at least once. */
      if (RL_ISSTATE(RL_STATE_TTYCSAVED) == 0)
        return;

      RESET_SPECIAL (_rl_tty_chars.t_erase);
      RESET_SPECIAL (_rl_tty_chars.t_kill);

    #  if defined (VLNEXT) && defined (TERMIOS_TTY_DRIVER)
      RESET_SPECIAL (_rl_tty_chars.t_lnext);
    #  endif /* VLNEXT && TERMIOS_TTY_DRIVER */

    #  if defined (VWERASE) && defined (TERMIOS_TTY_DRIVER)
      RESET_SPECIAL (_rl_tty_chars.t_werase);
    #  endif /* VWERASE && TERMIOS_TTY_DRIVER */
    }
```

You can see the `stty` names used in the structures: **`erase`**, **`kill`** and **`lnext`**.  There's no **`discard`**.  `bash` doesn't set it (or reset it).